# Send email with proxy IP using CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY

Tags: php, curl, proxy, smtp

What is the problem here? I can't send email with my server but with a different IP address (for example proxy here).

> **Warning:** curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in [link] on line 12

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "103.10.22.242");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY,true);
curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);

$to = "you@your-domainname.com";
$nameto = "Who To";
$from = "script@your-domainname.com";
$namefrom = "Who From";
$subject = "Hello World Again!";
$message = "World, Hello!";
mail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An IP address can be represented by a single number. I Googled IP to Long Converter and [found this](http://www.smartconversion.com/unit_conversion/IP_Address_Converter.aspx).

The equivalent long value for your IP is **1728714482**.